# .gitignore not working on heroku

Tags: git, heroku, laravel-5, gitignore

I am not able to stop pushing files to heroku server even mentioned in .gitignore file of laravel 5.2. Below is my gitignore file. I want to stop pushing images of **"public/assets/images"** folder to override old images.

```
public/assets/images
node_modules
public/storage
storage/*.key
vendor
*.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
*.env
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a file is committed in git, adding it to .gitignore doesn't have any effect on it.

You need to remove the files from git and commit the removal, then the .gitignore settings should have the effect that you want.

Comment: Working fine on github but when deploying to heroku then it does not stop the folder to override.